# How to switch to a root user from a custom user without password or keyless switch to root user on RHEL?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I wanted to assign a certain functionality to one of the custom users created on a linux based machine. It is to allow to switch to root without the providing the password.The motivation is simple i don't want to assign root privileges to the custom user but want to enable it to switch to root without a password

Comment: Have you tried to google this? Why did usual solutions not work for you? Did you run into any problems?

Comment: i have tried googling it but couldn't really find anything or concrete enough for me to try it

Comment: I've just tried with "linux root without password" and [this was the 2nd result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294531/use-root-privilege-without-password)

Comment: That's not the required functionality. The idea here is not to give the root privilege to the user directly ,it is to allow the user to switch to root user without a password , not execute root commands without password. For example :

Login as goldriver to server & then switch to root by "su -" to root user without password or to enable a keyless entry to root user

Comment: @Kefka I am not sure if it will allow me to switch to root user without password

Comment: You can combine it with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) to allow only `sudo su` without a password.

Comment: Is there any other method apart from modifying the /etc/sudoers file? For example if i have like 10-20 custom users, would i need to make entries in this file each time a user is created to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: You can apply this to a group rather than specific users, just use `%groupname` (with `%` prefix) rather than `username`.

Comment: So i understand then that  modification of /etc/sudoers is necessary to achieve this functionality and that there is no way to bypass sudo and simply login to root user using "su -" without password instead of using "sudo su -"?

Comment: AFAIK no, `su` isn't intended to do that.